# Accessing a variable in parent scope from within a call back function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have a bit of a code that looks like this in AngularJS,

```
$scope.loadItems = function($query){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/query=' + $query}).then(
        function($response){
            $scope.result = $response['data'];
        }, function($response){$scope.result = [];});
        return $scope.result;
      }
```

$scope.loadItems needs to be assigned a array variable. I am acquiring this array by doing an Ajax call inside one of those callback functions of the Ajax call. However I am forced to set the array I obtained as an attribute of $scope variable to make it accessible in the scope of the outer most function which I don't like as it doesn't feel right(I am sure I will start using $scope.result somewhere without thinking about it much and will end up with some very wierd results). Is there any way I can pass the array I obtained from the success callback function to the outer most function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```js
$scope.loadItems = function($query){
        $scope.result = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/query=' + $query}).then(
        function($response){
            return $response['data'];
        }, function($response){ return [];});
        return $scope.result;
      }
```

*If this doesn't work let me know on the comment, I'll delete this answer.*